# Android data binding is not working with <merge> attributes

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to use databinding with custom views (a possible usage George Mount showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817565/2938966)).

One can't imagine building compound views without `<merge>` tag. However, in this situation databinding fails:

`MyCompoundView` class:

```
public class MyCompoundView extends RelativeLayout {

MyCompoundViewBinding binding;

public MyCompoundView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    binding = MyCompoundViewBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
}
```

`my_compound_view.xml`: by `app:isGone="@{!data.isViewVisible}"` i hoped to control the visibility of the whole compound view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>
        <variable name="data" type="com.example.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <merge
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isGone="@{!data.isViewVisible}">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{data.imagePhotoUrl}"/>

         <!-- tons of other views-->

    </merge>

</layout>
```

The compiler errors:

```
Error:(13) No resource identifier found for attribute 'isGone' in package 'com.example'
Error:(17, 21) No resource type specified (at 'isGone' with value '@{!data.isViewVisible}').
```

I have all needed `@BindingAdapter` methods. Now I inherit the view from `FrameLayout` and use `<RelativeLayout>` instead of `<merge>` - and it works. But I have extra nested layout.

**Question:** `merge` attrs are ignored. Is there any way to workaround that?

Android Studio 1.5.1 stable

Gradle plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`

Comment: it's best if you use <include> instead of <merge>.

Comment: @Rakeeb Rajbhandari, yes, databinding does work ok with `<include>` tag. However, this will not solve the problem of extra viewgroup while inflating custom view.

Comment: Please have a look at my question. I'm using include tag and inner class. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45143721/5214893

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no merge object after inflation, so there is nothing to assign values to with a merge tag.  I can't think of any binding tag that will work on merge.

You can assign the tag to the root element and use the BindingAdapter to do what you want.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>
        <variable name="data" type="com.example.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <merge
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            app:isGone="@{!data.isViewVisible}"
            android:id="@+id/image_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{data.imagePhotoUrl}"/>
         <!-- tons of other views-->
    </merge>
</layout>
```

If you want to do something with the Binding class itself, you can use the DataBindingUtil to find the object from the View.

```
@BindingAdapter("isGone")
public static void setGone(View view, boolean isGone) {
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.findBinding(view);
    //... do what you want with the binding.
}
```

Comment: Exactly Android developers mentioned about it in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#layout_details)

Comment: Could you elaborate your advice with some code? Thank you :)

Comment: Hello, I can't get the merge tag to work. It shows the error `Element merge is not allowed here`. See: https://pastebin.com/QhQKYN71

Comment: Here, `merge is not allowed here` is just a warning but it's [a known bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37150098)

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can use `<merge>` tag inside `<include>` and do data binding.

Ex:

**incl_button.xml**

```
<layout>
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button android:id="btn"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Click"
         />

    </merge>
</layout>
```

**fragment_example.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/incl_button"
            android:id="@+id/layout_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**ExampleFragment.kt**

```
binding.layoutBtn.btn.setOnClickListener{
   //...
}
```