# Workaround of the problem with Data Binding not supporting merge tag

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a custom view group, which extends `LinearLayour`, inflates XML layout file with `<merge>` tags and references the views from this layout file.

CustomViewGroup.java

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomViewGroup(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        inflate(context, R.layout.view_custom, this);

        this.<TextView>findViewById(R.id.first).setText("Hello");
        this.<TextView>findViewById(R.id.second).setText("World");
    }
}
```

view_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

Instead of using `findViewById`, I'd like to use Data Binding Library to generate references to the views, however the library doesn't support `<merge>` tag. I've found a workaround which includes adding `LinearLayout` into XML layout file, and making `CustomViewGroup` extends `FrameLayout`:

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomViewGroup(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final ViewCustomBinding binding = ViewCustomBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);

        binding.first.setText("Hello");
        binding.second.setText("World");
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This solution has one drawback - now the view hierarchy is deeper, because there is one redundant `FrameLayout`.

Is there a method to use Data Binding Library, with all the advantages of the `<merge>` tag, i.e. without making the view hierarchy deeper?

Comment: What do you mean by merge??

Comment: @AngusTay I mean `<merge>` tag described here: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge

Comment: @pskink If I replace `<merge>` with `<CustomViewGroup>`, I'll inflate `CustomViewGroup` inside `CustomViewGroup`

Comment: Too bad, Android Team still didn't work on it even after 2 years.

Comment: Do you find this useful? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590608/android-data-binding-is-not-working-with-merge-attributes