# Why use ViewBinding over DataBinding?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

As we can read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) there is very small difference between `ViewBinding` and `Databinding`.

> - The data binding library processes only data binding layouts created using the `<layout>` tag.
> - View binding doesn't support layout variables or layout expressions, so it can't be used to bind layouts with data in XML.

Are there any other differences that developers should be aware of? Why create something new with such a small difference?

Someone please explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why create something new with such a small difference?

Build times for view binding are much lower than for data binding, because there is a lot less work involved. For small projects, this may not matter. For large projects, the impacts on build times can be substantial.

Comment: can you please explain what it means by lot less work?

Answer (score 1):

Advantages of viewbinding is speed and efficiency. It has a shorter build time because it avoids the overhead and performance issues associated with databinding due to annotation processors affecting databinding's build time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the reasons why you might prefer View Binding over Data Binding:

> The data binding library processes only data binding layouts created using the `<layout>` tag. Data binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of layout followed by a data element and a view root element

And this causes problems when intending to use merge:

> Data binding doesn't support **include as a direct child of a merge element**. For example, the following layout isn't supported:
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <layout
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    <data>
>        <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>    </data>    <merge><!-- Doesn't work -->
>        <include layout="@layout/name"
>            bind:user="@{user}"/>
>        <include layout="@layout/contact"
>            bind:user="@{user}"/>    </merge> 
> </layout>
> ```

Comment: it does support include now

Comment: @user158 it doesn't support **include inside merge**

Comment: it's possible please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696104/7356355) I do not think currently `include`, `merge` tags work with ViewBinding since bugs are reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143729912) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143683987)