# Get binding from view class

Tags: android, data-binding, android-custom-view

I have a CustomView class with a databound layout that takes a variable. In the layout that contains the CustomView, I want to pass an attribute into the CustomView, and have that CustomView pass that attribute into its own layout's binding. Here's what I have:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout
{
public CustomView(Context inContext, AttributeSet inAttrs)
{
    super(inContext, inAttrs);

    inflate(inContext, R.layout.custom_view, null);
}



@BindingAdapter({"app:variable"})
public static void SetVariable(CustomView inCustomView, VariableType inMyVariable)
{
    CustomViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(inCustomView);

    binding.setMyVariable(inMyVariable);
}
}
```

This crashes trying to extract the binding from the view. Is this even possible? Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void xxx.databinding.CustomViewBinding.setVariableType(xxx.VariableType)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at xxx.CustomView.SetDynamicList(CustomView.java:32)
                                                                            at xxx.MyFragmentBinding.executeBindings(MyFragmentBinding.java:116)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:350)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:167)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$7.doFrame(ViewDataBinding.java:233)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And if I change

```
DataBindingUtil.getBinding(inCustomView)
```

to

```
DataBindingUtil.bind(inCustomView)
```

then I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View is not a binding layout
                                                                            at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:166)
                                                                            at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:140)
                                                                            at xxx.CustomView.SetDynamicList(CustomView.java:30)
                    -                                                        at xxx.databinding.MyFragmentBinding.executeBindings(MyFragmentBinding.java:116)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:350)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:167)
                                                                            at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$7.doFrame(ViewDataBinding.java:233)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This might imply that the layout file is not formatted for databinding, but it is. It has the layout element, and the data element with variables and everything.

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Provided, along with a little more info

Answer (score 32):

You must bind the inflated view to create the data binding. In your example, you're binding the *container* of the layout.

You can do this in several ways. The easiest is to bind it as part of inflation:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout
{
  CustomViewBinding mBinding;
  public CustomView(Context inContext, AttributeSet inAttrs)
  {
    super(inContext, inAttrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(inContext);
    // I assume you want it inflated into this ViewGroup
    mBinding = CustomViewBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
  }

  public void setVariable(CustomView inCustomView, VariableType inMyVariable) {
    mBinding.setVariable(inMyVariable);
  }
  ...
}
```

You don't really need a binding adapter unless you don't want the setter as part of your custom view. In that case, you'll still need a way to get the binding, so you'll need to add something like this:

```
public CustomViewBinding getBinding() { return mBinding; }
```

so that your binding adapter works.

If you know that the LinearLayout contents are all going to be from the inflated view, you can use a binding adapter like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:variable"})
public static void setVariable(CustomView inCustomView, VariableType inMyVariable)
{
    if (inCustomView.getChildCount() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    View boundView = inCustomView.getChildAt(0);
    CustomViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(boundView);

    binding.setMyVariable(inMyVariable);
}
```

If your custom view isn't very custom, you can simply include your layout directly:

```
<include layout="@layout/custom_view" app:variable="@{myVariableValue}"/>
```

You would, of course, have to move the LinearLayout into the custom_view.xml.

Comment: Hey @George can you describe how CustomViewBinding  class generated ?

Comment: Suppose I have CustomViewPager class so should i have to write a xml for this also to generate CustomViewPagerBinding class?

Comment: ignore this message i have solve this issue by making extra xml for CustomViewPager thanks :).

Comment: Does the custom view have to have a XML layout file? How to do this if custom view is a subclass of TextView such that no XML layout file involved?

Comment: CustomViewBinding is just the name of the generated binding when the XML layout resource is custom_view.xml. A Binding class is only generated for a layout resource. A custom text view can be in a layout resource, but it wouldn't have one itself. This question involved a custom view that had a custom layout resource describing how it looks.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, this is how it worked for me:

**XML:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/containerView"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

.....


</layout>
```

**Java Class:**

```
GeneralOverviewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind((findViewById(R.id.containerView)));
```

This basically returns the binding for the given layout root or creates a binding if one does not exist.

Comment: tried this but does not work