# Recyclerview with ListAdapter DiffCallback and Undo on swipe option

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

Let's say that there is a simple scenario:

- `user` table for storing user details
- `user_images` to store in a `image_path` field the paths of images in the phone's storage.

There is a list of users shown in a `RecyclerView` and the user can Swipe to delete a row. The adapter is a `ListAdapter` and the data comes from Room as being `LiveData`

Workflow I was thinking is like this:

1. remove the swiped item from the adapter and update the recyclerview
2. show a Snack with Undo option
3. on Snack if user presses Undo, re-add the item in the `ListAdapter` and update the recyclerview. If the user does not press Undo and the Snack gets dismissed after timeout, delete the rows from `user`, `user_images` and also delete all the images from the storage related to `user_images` in `image_path`

...

```
override fun onSwiped(...){
  val deletedItem = listAdapter.currentList.get(index)

  //REMOVE FROM THE ADAPTER HERE

  val snack = Snackbar.make(...)
  snack.setAction(...){
      //RE-ADD TO ADAPTER HERE
  }

  snack.addCallback(...){
    override fun onDismissed(...){
       //do the actual deletes
    }
  }

}
```

...

The issue is using the ListAdapter. As you may know it uses DiffCallBack to manage the view updates and calling `adapter.submitList(list)` does not trigger any updates as it receives the same list. ([ListAdapter not updating item in reyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726385/listadapter-not-updating-item-in-reyclerview))
So in order to be able to remove item, I would need to:

- get the adapter's `currentList` as `Mutable` updatebleList
- remove the item from the updatebleList
- re-submit the list to the adapter `adapter.submitList(updatebleList.toList())`
- in case of Undo, re-add the item to the updatebleListand submit it again as a new list `adapter.submitList(updatebleList.toList())`

As you see, there are a lot of list re-creation in order to properly submit.
Is there a better/simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: You should have an intermediate representation of your data, containing the deletion state. Because managing that in the activity/fragment is not the place to perform that.

Comment: you need to remove it from database table anyway.. and then insert it again, and then everything automatically re-appears (LiveData from Database Query and sumbit func of RecyclerView)

Answer (score 1):

I have simply apply swipe to delete functionality in MainActivity via creating new ItemTouchHelper().
You can check the sample code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ercanduman/NoteTakingApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ercanduman/notetakingapp/activity/MainActivity.java).