# Avoid calling submitList in ListAdapter constructor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I'm refactoring a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to `ListAdapter`. One unexpected thing after 3 staring hours is that `submitList()` has to be called when the list is first populated.

I always thought that `submitList()` was the unification of `notify*()`, which means it is called on *subsequent* list modifications. However, with `ListAdapter`, even the first time (`this.someList = list;` inside constructor) is counted as modification, and `submitList(this.someList)` has to be called right after that.

Is there any way to avoid calling `submitList()` inside the constructor?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031492/8244632) help?

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I don't think it is relevant to my question, and I'm not in the right mood to dig the source code. Your link's problem: rendered fine 1st time, edit data, no render. My problem: no render at all, add new data, render 1st time. Anyway, I know the questioner's frustration =))).