# Implementation of Swipe to Delete using ViewModel and LiveData in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-livedata

I want to implement **swipe to delete** functionality in a RecyclerView which is populated with data from an API.
There is a `ViewModel` class and data is fetched from API to a `allOrders: MutableLiveData<MutableList<ModelClass>>` in ViewModel. The observer in Fragment updates the RecyclerView Adapter on LiveData change:

```
viewModel.allOrders.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    adapter.submitList(it)
})
```

I want to delete the swiped item in RecyclerView from `allOrders: MutableLiveData<MutableList<ModelClass>>`, so this is the function to do that in ViewModel class:

```
fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
    _allOrders.value?.removeAt(index)
}
```

But removing an item from `MutableLiveData<MutableList>` doesn't even notify the observer.

**What is the best practice for implementing such a functionality using
ViewModel and LiveData in Kotlin?**

**UPDATE**

I change **deletItem** function to this:

```
fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
    _allOrders.value = _allOrders.value?.also { list ->
    list.removeAt(index)
}
```

Now the observer is being notified, but `adapter.submitList(it)` doesn't change RecyclerView to new list. Scrolling the RecyclerView throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The adapter class looks like this one in [codeslab example](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/RecyclerViewDiffUtilDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, submitList() was not updating the view. Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50062174)

Basically, the adapter class stores a reference to current list (call it curList). When submitList is called with a newList, it compares curList and newList, if they reference the same list, it silently ignores updating the view.

In the above solutions we are removing element in the list, so the reference is not changing. So when we call submitList with this new list, the function sees it as the same list, so it ignores updating view.

One solution is:

```
adapter.submitList(null);
adapter.submitList(it);
```

But this will call OnBindView on all list elements again, ignoring the DiffUtilCallBack.

Another is to create a shallow copy:

```
adapter.submitList(mutableListOf(it))
```

Make sure you call submitList this way at all places where the list changes.

or make `allOrders: MutableLiveData<List<ModelClass>>` and:

```
fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
    // minus() creates a new list automatically
    _allOrders.value = _allOrders.value?.minus(_allOrders.value?.get(index))
}
```

In this way, you can just call submitList(it).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a 'reference list' in your ViewModel and operate on it. When the item is removed, then update the list and update the LiveData with this list:

```kotlin
class YourViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private var ordersList = MutableList<ModelClass>()
    val _allOrders = MutableLiveData<MutableList<ModelClass>>()
    
    fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
        ordersList.removeAt(index)
        _allOrders.value = ordersList
    }
}
```

You can also use Kotlin scope function called `also` without adding the globally scoped list if you don't need it and operate only on values emitted by LiveData:

```kotlin
fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
    _allOrders.value = _allOrders.value?.also { list -> 
       list.removeAt(index)
   }
}
```

Comment: I used `also` and it notifies observer, but calling `submitList(newList)` on adapter don't delete item in RecyclerView. Scrolling the RecyclerView throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` . why is that?

Comment: Can you paste the Adapter class?

Comment: I implemented adapter like this one in [codelabs examples](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/RecyclerViewDiffUtilDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt)

Answer (score 1):

The way you've implemented `deleteItem()`, circumvents the LiveData class. You're getting a reference to the List that is stored as it's value, and directly manipulating it, LiveData is unaware that anything has happened to the data.

Since Kotlin is a pass-by-reference language, the value that LiveData is holding is just a reference to the memory where the array is held, which means that if you change the contents of the array, the `LiveData.value` has not actually changed in any way.

You'll have to set a new value on the LiveData in order to update it and notify observers, in the case of a List, you're either gonna have to create a whole new List and set it as the value, or do this:

```kotlin
fun deleteItem(index: Int) {
    _allOrders.value?.removeAt(index)
    _allOrders.value = _allOrders.value
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. LiveData notifies observer, but calling `submitList(newList)` on adapter don't delete item in RecyclerView. Scrolling the RecyclerView throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` . My RecyclerView adapter looks like [this one](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/RecyclerViewDiffUtilDataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt)

Comment: Are you using the `also {}` solution from the other answer? I think that might actually be breaking it. Try doing it how I said here. I think also gets called after the assignment, which would make it pointless.

Comment: I tried your solution too. still throwing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: sure. it's  available in Codeslab example link