# Diff util not updating UI - Multitype recyclerview - Model contains lists

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a recyclerview which displays multiple viewholders containing horizontal rows, grids, vertical lists etc so my Model that I pass to the recyclerview has a few different lists contained in it.

Some of the data in the List is genereated by dagger at compile time and other lists within that model are updated when the network requests from the api completes.

The problem is when I pass the updated List the UI never updates. I have to move into another screen then come back again to see the UI updated or just manually pass false in the diff util areContentsTheSame

Model

```
data class Model(
var id: String,
val viewType: String,
val title: Int?,
val textColour: Int,
val order: Int,
var header: HeaderModel?,
var videoList: List<VideoModel>? = emptyList(),
var quotesList: List<QuotesModel>? = emptyList(),
var tileList: List<TileModel>? = emptyList(),
var gratitudeList: List<String>? = emptyList(),
) {
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

    other as Model

    if (id != other.id) return false
    if (viewType != other.viewType) return false
    if (title != other.title) return false
    if (textColour != other.textColour) return false
    if (order != other.order) return false
    if (header != other.header) return false
    if (videoList != other.videoList) return false
    if (quotesList != other.quotesList) return false
    if (tileList != other.tileList) return false
    if (gratitudeList != other.gratitudeList) return false

    return true
}
```

Adapter Diff

```
 val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Model>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: Model,
        newItem: Model
    ): Boolean {
        val value = oldItem.id == newItem.id
        return value
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: Model,
        newItem: Model
    ): Boolean {
         return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)

fun submitList(list: List<Model>?) {
    differ.submitList(list)
    //  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Fragment

```
homeViewModel.viewState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { viewState ->
        if (viewState != null) {
            viewState.modelList?.let { list ->
                homeAdapter?.submitList(list)
            }
        }
    })
```

Update to the videoList

```
 fun updateListVideos(list:  List<VideoModel>?) {
    val update = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()
    setViewState(update.apply{ modelList?.get(1)?.videoList = list)
}
```

I've read so many other questions on this that suggest in the live data observer pass list.toMutableList to essentially create a new list - Tried it doesnt work. The only hack that worked was calling submitList(null) before submitting the list which causes the whole UI to "flash". Other than that Ive had to revert back to NotifyDataSetChange which obviously defeats the whole purpose of having a diff util. Any help solving this would be great.

Comment: you should call ``notifyDataSetChanged()`` after data has been added/updated

Comment: Then whats the point of diff util?

Comment: What's the difference between Model and SectionModel? It's really weird that you're overriding `equals` for a `data class`, but also in your implementation you are assuming the other object being compared to Model is a SectionModel, which is not guaranteed. Also, a tip: Avoid nullable List properties, since it's easier to work with non-null Lists and just use `emptyList()` to represent them when they contain nothing.

Comment: The sectionModel was a typo, I edited the question. The overriding changees nothing Ive also edited that back. Thanks for the tip on empty lists

Comment: Try with `StateFlow` and `collectLatest`. It doesn't update if dataset is the same and try debugging if it posted new value.

Comment: I'd step through with the debugger and make sure your diffing is definitely working - and your ``updateListVideos`` code too, there's some weird logic going on in there. How come you're populating a list for ``updatedVideoList`` and immediately overwrite it if ``updateList`` isn't null? If I'm reading it right the entire thing could be replaced with `val update = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()` and `setViewState(update.apply { modelList?.get(1)?.videoList = list })`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726385/listadapter-not-updating-item-in-recyclerview) might be helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the coding tips guys, really appreciate it. I refactored to your suggestion @cactustictacs much cleaner and simpler. The problem is the "list" comes from the viewstate. I only update the videolist in that list then submit it so the diff util isnt recognising it as a new list. Its the same list with an updated video list if that makes sense. I dont know how to make it realise the video list within the List<Model> has been updated from empty to not empty

Comment: Well the reason I mentioned it was because it looked like you were trying to do some specific processing in there (including creating a new copy of a list), but ultimately you discard all that and just set the ``list`` parameter on your original object. So maybe things weren't being updated the way you expected. Does ``getCurrentViewStateOrNew`` return the same instance each time? Because if it does, `update.modelList?.get(1)` is potentially the same instance too, and your ``Model#equals`` function returns true immediately with that `===` referential equality check, before it checks the lists

Comment: If you're mutating the same ``Model`` instance by setting a new ``videoList`` on it, that will be visible in any other collections that contain that instance too, because you're updating it "in place" instead of passing a new object with different state. So the update will be invisible to the diff tool, because it's just comparing the same object with itself - it doesn't know that the object has changed since the last comparison. This is all guesswork on what's going on internally, but hopefully it can help you track things down. Stick a breakpoint in ``equals`` and debug it, see what's up!

Comment: Yeah the GetCurrentViewStateOrNew gets the live data List<Model> which contains the child list<VideoModel>. Its just one parent list and the child list gets updated after the data is returned from the youtube network request. I dont want to wait to set the recyclerview UI on the network request so I set the layout immediately then call the submit list when the video data is ready.  But Its the same parent list with an updated child  video list.

Comment: When I set the break point the old item and new item are showing as being exactly the same. Infact I have to submit list.ToMutableList() to trick it into starting the diff util. If I dont do that the diffing wont even start. But when it does start it just returns true for everything. Im a bit stumped on how to solve this. I just need it to recognise when the child video list has been updated and show the videos on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your old and new lists have the same referenced fields. That's why, diff util is not recognizing the change. You should either update your `equals override` and compare each field of lists or when you want to update your oldList do it like below:

```
val newList = oldList.map { it.copy() }
homeAdapter?.submitList(newList)
```