# Is turning a mutableList into a new list for .submitList() too inefficient? - RecyclerView, ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-livedata, listadapter

I'm using a ListAdapter for my recyclerView and because I'm working with a mutableList in my viewModel, my recyclerView UI does not update the list if I just pass the same mutableList updated. The simple solution is to type 'it.toList()', but I worry this takes too long creating an completely new list. Is there a better way? Also, explaining how  '.toList()' works might help me understand this.

from:

```
viewModel.basicItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    recyclerAdapter.submitList(it)
}
```

to:

```
viewModel.basicItems.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    recyclerAdapter.submitList(it.toList())
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand how toList works, maybe just navigate into the source for it?  If you're worried about performance, have you performed any benchmarks?

Comment: You could also just call `notifyDataSetChanged` to force an update. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726385/listadapter-not-updating-item-in-recyclerview)

Comment: @DougStevenson The problem is that if the list becomes too big then it could take significantly longer copy it. I'm looking for a solution that takes up less time.

Comment: Less time compared to what?  What is the performance benchmark you're trying to achieve?  What's the fundamental, observable problem you're trying to solve? You only have a performance problem when you observe it under specific circumstances.

Comment: @TylerV That helped me understand my problem, it looks like .notifyDataSetChanged() is more expensive than .submitList() but maybe submitList() becomes more expensive given enough inputs. I want to know to what extent if any submitList() copying a list becomes too inneficient.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have not found problems using submitList() for my current program but since I will use this code in other programs I want to understand it to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: It sounds like premature optimization. If the list gets too large to easily copy in memory then you probably need to restructure more than just this part anyway. I wouldn't worry about it unless it becomes an actual problem.