# Android data binding inject ViewModel in custom view

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-viewmodel

I'm going off this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817565/4052264 to tie a data object to a custom view. However, after everything's set up my view is not being updated with the data and instead the `TextView` stays blank.
Here's my code (simplified, for the sake of fitting in here):

`activity_profile.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns...>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.ProfileViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <com.example.MyProfileCustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:viewModel="@{viewModel}">
</layout>
```

`view_profile.xml`:

```
<layout xmlns...>
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.ProfileViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{viewModel.name}">
</layout>
```

`MyProfileCustomView.kt`:

```
class MyProfileCustomView : FrameLayout {
    constructor...

    private val binding: ViewProfileBinding = ViewProfileBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)

    fun setViewModel(profileViewModel: ProfileViewModel) {
        binding.viewModel = profileViewModel
    }
}
```

`ProfileViewModel.kt`:

```
class ProfileViewModel(application: Application) : BaseViewModel(application) {
    val name = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        profileManager.profile()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(::onProfileSuccess, Timber::d)
    }

    fun onProfileSuccess(profile: Profile) {
        name.postValue(profile.name)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the API call to `profileManager.profile()` is successful, the `ViewProfileBinding` class is successfully created with the right setup. The issue is when I do `name.postValue(profile.name)` the view is not updated with the value of `profile.name`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing piece is to set a [Lifecycle Owner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#setlifecycleowner).

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(parent) //parent should be a fragment or an activity
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, this worked! I'm getting the activity with the following code `val activity: AppCompatActivity = (context as ContextThemeWrapper).baseContext as AppCompatActivity` `binding.setLifecycleOwner(activity)`

Comment: How to support two way databinding?

Answer (score 6):

The answered helped me and want to throw a util method you can add to get the `LifeCycleOwner`

```
fun getLifeCycleOwner(view: View): LifecycleOwner? {
    var context = view.context

    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is LifecycleOwner) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }

    return null
}
```

In your view:

```
getLifeCycleOwner(this)?.let{
   binding.setLifecycleOwner(it)
}
```