# Can we reference a view to another view in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-view

Suppose there are two TextView in a layout.  Is it possible to(just like referencing objects in Java)  change text of one view and by reference it automatically changes of other?  Yes,  then how? I am beginner and don't know the correct term of it.

Comment: Yes, It's Possible. You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799622/android-data-binding-with-a-custom-view

Comment: use dataBinding (ObservableField<>)